# find and select non-english character in text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some paragraph text in page that made with english and non-english words, I need to find english words with Javascript or jquery and insert  after and before these.

Comment: Do you mean non-ASCII characters, or words per se? Words like "monsieur" is not English but made up of ASCII characters.

Comment: Now that's a bit of a succinct question, any chance you pressed enter before adding a context and where you are currently stuck?

Comment: If it helps, a year ago I wrote some code to check if words were in a dictionary (though it wasn't a very good dictionary I used at that time) that is available on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140886/making-sure-a-sentence-exists-of-words-in-a-dictionary)

Comment: @Terry all of my text language is persian i need to select english words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean non-English character (not word), you can use regular expressions:

```
if (str.match(/^[a-zA-Z1-9.?!:;\- ]+$/g) === null) 
{
    //str contains non-English character(s) 
    // (You can add more characters to the block if you want to allow more. I may have missed something.)
}
```

If you mean non-English words, it's a bit more difficult, because then you are required to use some sort of resource (dictionary-like) to match each word. This is much more complicated.

Comment: all of my text language is persian i need to select english words

Comment: @MehryarS In that case this method won't work. Instead, use a dictionary-resource and try to match words from that one.